# Lollipop Chart: Assign Colours According to the Ascending Values of a Column Name Using R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a column (RMSE) in a data frame in which I want the colour (green, yellowgreen, yellow, orange, red) of a `lollipop chart` to vary according to the values of the column `RMSE`. I want the pop representing the lowest to be `green` while the pop representing the highest RMSE value to be `red

```
    df1 <- read.table(text =
                    "nbb_RMSE  9 0.2402482
                     mbb_RMSE  9 0.1023012
                     cbb_RMSE  8 0.2031448
                     tmbb_RMSE 4 0.2654746
                     tcbb_RMSE 9 0.4048711")

colnames(df1) <- c("Methods", "lb", "RMSE")

df1 |>
  dplyr::mutate(lb = as.factor(lb)) |>
  ggplot2::ggplot(ggplot2::aes(x = Methods, y = RMSE, colour = Methods)) + 
  ggplot2::geom_point(size = 4) + 
  ggplot2::geom_segment(ggplot2::aes(x = Methods, xend = Methods, yend = RMSE, y = 0)) + 
  ggplot2::scale_color_manual(values = c("green", "yellowgreen", "yellow", "orange", "red")) + 
  ggplot2::theme_bw()
```

This is [image: what I get]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar approach to @stephan's option:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- read.table(text =
                    "nbb_RMSE  9 0.2402482
                     mbb_RMSE  9 0.1023012
                     cbb_RMSE  8 0.2031448
                     tmbb_RMSE 4 0.2654746
                     tcbb_RMSE 9 0.4048711")

colnames(df1) <- c("Methods", "lb", "RMSE")

df1 |>
  mutate(colour = fct_reorder(Methods, RMSE)) |>
  ggplot(aes(Methods, RMSE, colour = colour)) + 
  geom_point(size = 4) + 
  geom_segment(aes(Methods, xend = Methods, yend = RMSE, y = 0)) + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c("green", "yellowgreen", "yellow", "orange", "red")) + 
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-06-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use a named color vector where you use `reorder` to assign the names according to the value of `RMSE`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

pal <- c("green", "yellowgreen", "yellow", "orange", "red")
names(pal) <- levels(reorder(df1$Methods, df1$RMSE))

df1 |>
  dplyr::mutate(lb = as.factor(lb)) |>
  ggplot2::ggplot(ggplot2::aes(x = Methods, y = RMSE, colour = Methods)) + 
  ggplot2::geom_point(size = 4) + 
  ggplot2::geom_segment(ggplot2::aes(x = Methods, xend = Methods, yend = RMSE, y = 0)) + 
  ggplot2::scale_color_manual(values = pal) + 
  ggplot2::theme_bw()
```

[image]